# CSS When hovering over sub menu, the ancestor menu disappears

Tags: html, css, menu

The website is:
!questions answered!

When I hover over my menu "About Us" the background turns black and the text white, then when I hover over the sub menu "Meet our team" the original "About Us" text disappears.

I think it might have to do with the header links? Or the ancestor

The custom CSS I've been working with is as follows:

```
#header .menu > li.current_page_item > a {
background-color: #2A60A2;
color: #ffffff;
}

#header .sub-menu > li.current_page_item {
background-color: #2A60A2;
}

#header .menu > li.current-menu-ancestor > a {
background-color: #2A60A2;
color: #fff;
}

#header .menu > li > a:hover {
background-color: #000; 
color: #fff;
}

#header .sub-menu li:hover {
background-color: #2A60A2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it from `#header .menu > li > a:hover` to `#header .menu > li:hover > a`

Comment: Worked Perfectly! Thank you so much, I've been stuck on this problem for so long haha.

Comment: Just read your CSS! You were telling it to change when the user was hovered on the `a` element. Once they move to the menu, they're no longer hovering the `a` are they?

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Remove this Line from custom.css

your CSS

```
 #header .menu > li.menu-hover > a,
 #header .menu > li.current_page_item > a,
 #header .menu > li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
 #header .menu > li > a:hover {
        color: #fff;
}
```

change it to

```
 #header .menu > li.current_page_item > a,
 #header .menu > li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
 #header .menu > li > a:hover {
        color: #fff;
}
```

remove this `#header .menu > li.menu-hover > a,`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this css in custom.css line 62.

```
    #header .menu > li.menu-hover > a, #header .menu > li.current_page_item > a, #header .menu > li.current-menu-ancestor > a, #header .menu > li > a:hover {
        color: #777;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  #header .header-links li.menu-parent.menu-hover {
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Add this into your css